# How to retrieve the value of a binding property of a RadioButton which is part of InputListItem and has aggregationbinding?

Tags: sapui5

I have the below code on jsbin that I am trying. I need to get the value of the "Id" property mentioned in the model "answers". Til now while trying I understood that I need to use the select event to alert the selected value.
I also tried using `event.getSource().getSelectedItem().getBindingContext().getObject().Id`
But I am not able to get the "Id" property value.
You can find the code which I am trying on below jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/peciqaq/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the `Id` from the binding model.

Change your `onSelectRadio` event handler to following:

```
if(!event.getParameter("selected")) return;
var oModel = event.getSource().getModel();
var sPath = event.getSource().getBindingContext().getPath()
alert(oModel.getProperty(sPath+"/Id"));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <title>List example</title>
      
        <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" 
                type="text/javascript"
                src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
                data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
                data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons, sap.m"
                data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex">
        </script>


        <!-- XML-based view definition mode="SingleSelectMaster" -->
        <script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
            <mvc:View
              controllerName="local.controller"
              xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
              xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"
              xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
              xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
              xmlns="sap.m">
          <List
         headerText="Awesome List"
      items="{/answers}"
            id="singleChoice"
            selectionChange="onSelectionChange">
      <items>
     <InputListItem label="{answerText}">
                <RadioButton select="onSelectRadio"/>
              </InputListItem>
      </items>
       </List>
          
          </mvc:View> 
        </script>

        <script>

            // Controller definition
            sap.ui.controller("local.controller", {
              onInit: function() {
                var oData =   {
                  "answers": [{
                      "Id":1,
                      "answerText": "Cats"
                  }, {
                      "Id":2,
                      "answerText": "Rabbits"
                  }, {
                      "Id":3,
                      "answerText": "Dogs"
                  }, {
                      "Id":4,
                      "answerText": "Hamsters"
                  }]
                };
                sap.ui.getCore().setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData));
              },
              /*onSelectionChange: function(event) {
                alert(event.getSource().getSelectedItem().getBindingContext().getObject().Id);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(event.getSource().getSelectedItem().getBindingContext().getObject()));
              },*/
              onSelectRadio: function(event){
    if(!event.getParameter("selected")) return;
    var oModel = event.getSource().getModel();
    var sPath = event.getSource().getBindingContext().getPath()
    alert(oModel.getProperty(sPath+"/Id"));
                //alert(this.byId("singleChoice").getSelectedItem());
                //alert(event.getSource().getSelectedItem().getBindingContext().getObject().Id);
              }
            });
           
            // Instantiate the View, assign a model
            // and display
            var oView = sap.ui.xmlview({
                viewContent: jQuery('#view1').html()
            });
               
            oView.placeAt('content');

        </script>

    </head>
 
    <body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect it worked but I am unable to understand what does the event.getParameter("selected") does and where is the parameter selected ? Is it becomes true / false depending on I click Radio buttons. Also if instead of radio buttons check boxes where there how can I get the multiple checkboxes Id's selected

Comment: @Allen: the property can be retrieved even better (without path concatenation):
var oBindingContext = event.getSource().getBindingContext();
oModel.getProperty("Id", oBindingContext);

https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Model.html#getProperty

Comment: @loki you can refer to API doc https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.RadioButton.html#event:select . select event is trigger when radio button is selected or unselected. For checkboxes, i guess you can loop over all the checkboxes and get selected ones.

Comment: @Allen         Thank you i will refer it.

Comment: @Allen in this process of learning I also learnt how to get the bindingcontext of named model. Thank you again for help.

Comment: @loki I'm glad i can help here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to put the Radio button in the list item if you need the single selection feature. Just make use of the standard [mode](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html#getMode) property of the List.

Then you will be able to use the "selectionChange" event on the List and take the id in the way that you mentioned in your question.

Comment: I need to display radiobuttons based on the items in my List aggregation binding that is the reason I am using RadioButton inside InputListItem and items

Comment: sorry I wasn't able to convey my problem properly. But I found the answer. Thank you for your help you are good tutor. I have also sent you linkedin request i hope there is no problem with it. And I am still beginner in Javascript and SAPUI5 so these questions.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the information you want (onSelectRadio function):

```
alert(event.getSource().getBindingContext().getObject().Id);
```

BUT you are doing a strange thing here : using a radio button you built yourself to detect the selcetion instead of leveraging the sapui5 List itself

You can use the list itself with the following code:

```
<List
    headerText="Awesome List"
    items="{/answers}"
    id="singleChoice"
    mode="SingleSelect"
    selectionChange="onSelectionChange">
    <items>
        <StandardListItem title="{answerText}"/>
    </items>
</List>
```

and then you can access the list selected item (alert(event.getSource().getSelectedItem().getBindingContext().getObject().Id); but this time in onSelectionChange function)

Comment: I need to provide RadioButtons which will contain the answerText as text/label so if one selects the radio button I need to get its corresponding Id

Comment: have you tried my proposal ? :) it does exactly that

Comment: ya i get the Ids value but I don't need StandardListItems I need radio buttons so if some way selects the radio button I can capture its Id property value and the number of radio buttons should be equal to those present in answerText because at the moment I am showing just one answers object in model there can be one more model where there would be only two answerTexts in such case only 2 radio buttons should be displayed instead of 4 hence I am using aggregation binding with List along with InputListItem and then inside it I am using radiobutton.I m missing something or doing something wrong.

Comment: you just use the list for layout perspective then ? just use the first 2 lines of my answers then :)

Comment: oh yes right I am using list for layout perspective. Ill try it thank you.

Comment: in this process of learning I also learnt how to get the bindingcontext of named model. Thank you again for help.